# dd past end of file

Tags: linux, dd

I run dd with of param which was a new file. I did seek (by mistake) to a large adrees (3gb) and wrote there the input file(3 gb) . Suprisingly, the file created was 4,29gb which is larger than the limitation of FAT32 if i am not mistaken. 
Did it possibly damaged the disk(if it wrote past the last file block) or it is not that stupid?
Thanks

Comment: You accidentally created a [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).  Read the Wikipedia article, it tells you everything you need to know about those creatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created something that's called a "[sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)".

A sparse file is a file with one or several "holes" in it.

The holes do not take up any space on the disk, and a program reading across a hole will get zeroes.

`ls -l` will report the *apparent* size of the file (large), whereas `du` will tell you the *real* size (on disk).

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, this is not really supported on fat32.Because of the File Allocation Table format, sparse files cannot be supported on those filesystems. When data is written at an offset higher than file size, all disk space for lower offsets is allocated, then file size is adjusted.